# Error in UseMethod("select_") : no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')" in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

I am trying to create a dataset out of this data:

[image]

I want to include the Asian, African American, Other, White and Hispanic Counts. In order to do this, I have tried the code:

```
library(dplyr)
race_mut <- race %>%
  filter(!is.na(race))
  select(race$African_American, race$White, race$Hispanic, race$Asian, race$Other)

race_mut
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Error in UseMethod("select_") : no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

How do I fix this?

Comment: Don't use `$` in `dplyr` pipes. Also you have missing `%>%` after `filter`. What are you trying to do with `filter(!is.na(race))` ? It would be helpful if you could provide a reproducible example along with expected output. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Comment: I took out the $, and with filter(is!na.(race) I'm removing all of the na from the number counts so I can sum it

Comment: The problem was completely fixed after adding the %>%, thank you!